# igot error while running my program:Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: mysql, spring-boot-starter

i am getting this error as   i want  to run the web program and connect my database with it

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

i want  to connect my database  but getting the above outcome .It says Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

My pomfile looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.programming</groupId>
  <artifactId>JuneSpringApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JuneSpringApplication Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<!--      <scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>8.0.33</version>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>JuneSpringApplication</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```